# Creating a list of files of watched directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I set up a watchfolder in one directory and want it to append each filmename into a list everytime a new file shows up.

Here's what im trying to do:

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    
#set file path

    #path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    path = "C:\\Users\\Ingest\\Downloads"

#logging
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    
#start observing
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    
#start
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()



var_1 = observer
directory_evaluation = []

for file in var_1:

    if file == "%.mxf" or "%.mov":
        directory_evaluation.append(file)
        print(directory_evaluation)
```

Apparently i cannot associate "observer" to a variable because it's not a iterable.
What can I do to fix it?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. The ``InotifyObserver`` object is simply not iterable. And you can, in fact, assign the object to any variable you want (e. g. ``var_1 = observer`` is valid, although unnecessary). Double check the docs on how to use the observer object properly.

Comment: I just quick-checked the docs and could not find any hint that this functionality is part of the package (correct me if I am wrong). In this case, it seems you have to implement it yourself. To help you, please try to re-phrase your problem and specify what you mean by "what they have in common" (Filename, size, etc.).

Comment: Im trying to get a list of every file dropping into two different directories and see what they have in common

I added a watchfolder to my directory, i junt want those file names to be listed to me after the recognition.

This works if i want the current files listed, but won't be useful is someone erases any of them:

```
extension1 = ".mov"

directory_evaluation = []

for arq in os.listdir(path):
    if arq.endswith(extension1):
        directory_evaluation.append(arq)

directory_evaluation.sort()
print("Ids: ", directory_evaluation)

```

Comment: @DocDriven

What I mean by 'having in common': 
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = [1, 2, 4]

what i want to return: [1, 2]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I assume that you currently have two lists of filenames that are located in two directories, `files_dir_A` and `files_dir_B`. You want the intersection of these lists. As filenames in a directory have to be unique, you can convert the lists to sets and use the built-in intersection operator for sets:

```
files_dir_A = [f for f in os.listdir('path/to/dir/A') if f.endswith(extension)]

files_dir_B = [f for f in os.listdir('path/to/dir/B') if f.endswith(extension)]

result = list(set(files_dir_A) & set(files_dir_B))
```

So given a concrete example, the lists look like this:

```
files_dir_A = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
files_dir_B = ['file2', 'file3', 'file4']

result = ['file2', 'file3']
```

Comment: this is what I've tried before. Problem, this code give me what I have on directory right now. I want a list do register the file name as they drop into the directory with the watchfolder. Like a log list, some kind of register or every single file send to that directory.

Comment: @FlaviaBarcellos Is ``inotify`` what you are looking for? https://pypi.org/project/inotify/